# Change the header and the menu colour on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm starting from scratch with javascript and want to ask you for some advices upon that pieces of code. I'm developing Joomla 3.2 website with Gantry template as default. My mission is to achieve the following. When a user access submenu (01, 02, 03 e.g.) derived from the parent item128 and scroll down the "rt-header" and the ""rt-block menu-block""should change the background colour. For example accessing menu 02, scroll down and the header menu goes yellow.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="rt-header">
<div class="rt-block logo-block">
<div class="rt-block menu-block">
<ul class="gf-menu l1">
    <li class="item128 parent">
        <a class="item" href"services">Services<span class="border-fixer"></span>::after</a>
        <div class="dropdown columns-1">
            <div class="column col1">
                <ul class="l2">
                    <li class ="item1"><a class="item" href="submenu-01">Submenu1</a></li>
                    <li class ="item2"><a class="item" href="submenu-02">Submenu2</a></li>
                    <li class ="item3"><a class="item" href="submenu-03">Submenu3</a></li>
                    <li class ="item4"><a class="item" href="submenu-04">Submenu1</a></li>
                    <li class ="item5"><a class="item" href="submenu-05">Submenu2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is it the CSS: (when child item is active the header and the menu blocks inherit those colours)

```
.gf-menu.l1 li.item1.active.last {background-color:#abcf39;}
.gf-menu.l1 li.item2.active.last {background-color:#f39512;}
.gf-menu.l1 li.item3.active.last {background-color:#f16e68;}
.gf-menu.l1 li.item4.active.last {background-color:#7ecde9;}
.gf-menu.l1 li.item5.active.last {background-color:#878787;}
```

...and the jQuery function: (header-color.js)

```
    function changeColor(){
var t = jQuery('.item142').offset().top - 100;


jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var x = jQuery(this).scrollTop(),
        item141 = jQuery('.item141'),
        item142 = jQuery('.item142'),
        item143 = jQuery('.item143'),
        item144 = jQuery('.item144'),
        item152 = jQuery('.item152');

    if (x >= item141.offset().top && x < (item141.offset().top + item141.height())) {
        jQuery('rt-header').css("background-color", "#990");
    }
    if (x >= item142.offset().top && x < (item142.offset().top + item142.height())) {
        jQuery('rt-header').css("background-color", "#ccc");
    }
    if (x >= item143.offset().top && x < (item143.offset().top + item143.height())) {

        jQuery('rt-header').css("background-color", "#949494");
    }
    if (x >= item144.offset().top && x < (item144.offset().top + item144.height())) {
        jQuery('rt-header').css("background-color", "orange");
    }
    if (x >= item152.offset().top && x < (item152.offset().top + item152.height())) {
        jQuery('rt-header').css("background-color", "purple");
    }
});
}
```

I'm loading the .js document in the index.php file of my template into the "head" section:
`<?php $gantry->addScript("header-color.js");?>` But on tracking I recieve the following message:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined " Is it my function written wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have a mixup in classes and ids. Your jquery looks for an item with an ID, but your html gives only a class, but no ID

```
item1 = jQuery('#item1'); // Looking for an item with ID "item1"
```

And then in your html, you have

```
<li class ="item1">...</li>
```

To fix the issue, you need to either use ID both places or use classes both places.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will correct it now and give a try.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking id in `item1 = jQuery('#item1')` whereas in your html you have given class names.

Try this in your js file

```
    item1 = jQuery('.item1'),
    item2 = jQuery('.item2'),
    item3 = jQuery('.item3'),
    item4 = jQuery('.item4'),
    item5 = jQuery('.item5');
```

Comment: Now I submitted the edited version the jQuary function. On tracking seems that there isn't errors but still is not working ?!

Comment: create a jsfiddle and share its link.

Comment: Here is it: Just to mention the HTML is created by default from the Joomla template(Gantry) http://jsfiddle.net/8JEgx/6/